# OMP parrallel being ignored in object file

Tags: gcc, linker, openmp, object-files

**NOTE:** I do not understand object files, linking, or make files very well. I only understand enough to get a program running

I'm working on a GPU accelerated version of a previous project of mine that works with no problems. I currently am testing a modified version of a make file I have used for other CUDA programs.

The file:

```
exe: main.o b.o

    gcc -fopenmp -L /usr/local/cuda/lib64 -o exe main.o b.o -lcudart -lglfw -lGL

main: 

    gcc -fopenmp -o main.o main.c -Ofast -march=native -mtune=native -lglfw -lGL -I /usr/local/cuda/include

b.o: b.cu b.h

    nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -ccbin clang-3.8 -c -o b.o b.cu
```

*b.cu is a CUDA file containing some test functions; it does not effect anything yet.*

When I run the compiled program, it only uses a single core, and runs at 1/4 the frame rate (this is what would be expected on a 4 core cpu).

I've Googled as many questions as I can, but I have not found any results that work for me.

System info:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

CPU: AMD A8-3850

GPU: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB

RAM: 7974MiB

GCC: 7.3.0

Comment: Please edit your questin for the purpose of somehow getting the content of your makefile clear. It is very important that you somehow make clear where you have blanks (" "), tabs ("\t") and newlines("\n"). The StackOverflow editor makes that quite hard, for its somewhat surprising handling of white space, but you have to somehow avoid any doubt on what is where.

Comment: Somebody else, with experience of best practices for quoting make files here, please propose how to meaningfully and helpfully show a make file here.

Comment: I'm (hopefully) asking a redundant question, but you are actually using `OpenMP pragma` instructions in your non-CUDA code, right? And not just hoping that your code will run on four cores perfectly parallelized just because you use `OpenMP` compile flag?

Comment: @Christian W yes, I use the #pragma parrallel, simd, etc. I have another version that works on all cores, but when I link the CUDA file it stops working.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'll try to make those eddits